# Popup on submitting a form

Tags: forms, ajax

Updated:I built a custom form that processes the data and returns `TRUE` or `FALSE`. I want to process the data by AJAX, and show a popup if the form returns `TRUE`. May anyone help me to complete the code? I am using AJAX with drupal for the very first time.

> i made some changes in the form

```
function invitecode_menu() {
$items['invitecode'] = array(
'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
'page arguments' => array('invitecode_nameform'),
'access callback' => TRUE,
'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM
);
return $items;
}
function invitecode_nameform() {
$form['invite_code'] = array(
'#title' => t('Invite Code'),
'#type' => 'textfield',
'#ajax' => array(
      'callback' => 'inviteform_nameform_callback',
      'wrapper' => '',
      'method' => 'replace',
      'effect' => 'fade',
      ),
);
$form['submit'] = array(
'#type' => 'submit',
'#value' => 'submit',
);
return $form;
}
function invitecode_nameform_validate($form, &$form_state) {
$code1= $form_state['values']['invite_code'];
  if (!empty($code1)) {
    $code = regcode_use($code1);
    if (!is_object($code)) {
        drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'jqevent') .'/incorrect.js');
    }
    if (is_object($code)) {
        $_SESSION['regcode']=$form_state['values']['invite_code'];
        drupal_add_css(drupal_get_path('module', 'jqevent') .'/jqevent.css');
        drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'jqevent') .'/jqevent.js');
        $form1=drupal_get_form('user_register_form');
        print "<div id='popupContact'><a class='popupContactClose'>x</a>".drupal_render($form1)."</div>";
    }
}}
function invitecode_nameform_submit($form, &$form_state) {
$_SESSION['regcode']=$form_state['values']['invite_code'];
}
```

if i do not use the print function in validate() it simply give me the popup with no data inside. But using the print statement as i require the form inside the popup it gives me error inside the the popup like

```
> An AJAX HTTP error occurred. HTTP Result Code: 200 Debugging
> information follows. Path: /may18/?q=system/ajax StatusText: OK
> ResponseText: x Username * Spaces are allowed; punctuation is not
> allowed except for periods, hyphens, apostrophes, and underscores.
> E-mail address * A valid e-mail address. All e-mails from the system
> will be sent to this address. The e-mail address is not made public
> and will only be used if you wish to receive a new password or wish to
> receive certain news or notifications by e-mail. Password * Confirm
> password * Provide a password for the new account in both fields.
> Status  Blocked  Active  Roles  authenticated user  administrator 
> Notify user of new account  Registration Code Registration Code 
> Select the newsletter(s) to which you wish to subscribe. Coutallure
> newsletter  Give us permission to Contact you by email 
> [{"command":"settings","settings":{"basePath":"\/may18\/","ajaxPageState":{"theme":"maytheme","theme_token":"WZd5UzEZYK-b_Rh5bxi4rao3d1UNF5KWVloXCPZ9WuI","css":{"sites\/all\/modules\/jqevent\/jqevent.css":1},"js":{"sites\/all\/modules\/jqevent\/jqevent.js":1}},"overlay":{"paths":{"admin":"node\/*\/edit\nnode\/*\/delete\nnode\/*\/revisions\nnode\/*\/revisions\/*\/revert\nnode\/*\/revisions\/*\/delete\nnode\/add\nnode\/add\/*\noverlay\/dismiss-message\nuser\/*\/shortcuts\nnode\/*\/simplenews\nadmin\nadmin\/*\nbatch\ntaxonomy\/term\/*\/edit\nuser\/*\/cancel\nuser\/*\/edit\nuser\/*\/edit\/*\ndevel\/*\nnode\/*\/devel\nnode\/*\/devel\/*\ncomment\/*\/devel\ncomment\/*\/devel\/*\nuser\/*\/devel\nuser\/*\/devel\/*\ntaxonomy\/term\/*\/devel\ntaxonomy\/term\/*\/devel\/*","non_admin":"admin\/structure\/block\/demo\/*\nadmin\/reports\/status\/php"},"ajaxCallback":"overlay-ajax"},"password":{"strengthTitle":"Password
> strength:","hasWeaknesses":"To make your password
> stronger:","tooShort":"Make it at least 6
> characters","addLowerCase":"Add lowercase letters","addUpperCase":"Add
> uppercase letters","addNumbers":"Add numbers","addPunctuation":"Add
> punctuation","sameAsUsername":"Make it different from your
> username","confirmSuccess":"yes","confirmFailure":"no","weak":"Weak","fair":"Fair","good":"Good","strong":"Strong","confirmTitle":"Passwords
> match:","username":"mujtabamir"}},"merge":true},{"command":"insert","method":"prepend","selector":"head","data":"\u003clink
> type=\"text\/css\" rel=\"stylesheet\"
> href=\"http:\/\/localhost\/may18\/sites\/default\/files\/css\/css_-j0N5j7w-7YCgITTN-240MV-bqldIA1OJJebmoiZ80Y.css\"
> media=\"all\"
> \/\u003e\n","settings":null},{"command":"insert","method":"prepend","selector":"head","data":"\u003cscript
> type=\"text\/javascript\"
> src=\"http:\/\/localhost\/may18\/sites\/default\/files\/js\/js_IP9kSDhraOOcZHaQjBKqa_pUy3Jsg_WBiSr0qKQUQ4E.js\"\u003e\u003c\/script\u003e\n","settings":null}]
```

Comment: As side note, a form submission handler should not use `print`.

Comment: how i can add a drupal form to the popup div in this case?

Comment: See my answer; it's the AJAX callback that should return an array of form items that is rendered in the zone where the wrapper is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API documentation contains a section titled [AJAX Examples](http://api.drupal.org/api/examples/ajax_example--ajax_example.module/group/ajax_examples/7).

What I see wrong in your code is the form submission handler that output something using `print`. The purpose of a form submission handler is generally saving the submitted values in the database (e.g. using `variable_set()`), printing a message using [drupal_set_message()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_set_message/7), and redirecting the user to another page, if it is necessary.
It's the AJAX callback that should return the HTML to output in a specific section of the page, or returning the array containing elements that needs to be rendered. [ajax_example_autocheckboxes_callback()](http://api.drupal.org/api/examples/ajax_example--ajax_example.module/function/ajax_example_autocheckboxes_callback/7) reports the following text:

> Since #ajax['callback'] return can be HTML or a renderable array (or an array of commands), we can just return a piece of the form. See [AJAX Advanced Commands](http://api.drupal.org/api/examples/ajax_example--ajax_example_advanced.inc/7) for more details on AJAX framework commands.

What returned from the AJAX callback is rendered where the wrapper, which is a CSS ID, is present. For example, in the auto-checkboxes example, the "#wrapper" is used in the following way.

```
  $form['howmany_select'] = array(
    '#title' => t('How many checkboxes do you want?'), 
    '#type' => 'select', 
    '#options' => array(
      1 => 1,
      2 => 2,
      3 => 3,
      4 => 4,
    ), 
    '#default_value' => $num_checkboxes, 
    '#ajax' => array(
      'callback' => 'ajax_example_autocheckboxes_callback', 
      'wrapper' => 'checkboxes-div',
      //'method' defaults to replaceWith, but valid values also include
      // append, prepend, before and after.
      // 'method' => 'replaceWith',
      // 'effect' defaults to none. Other valid values are 'fade' and 'slide'.
      // See ajax_example_autotextfields for an example of 'fade'. 
      'effect' => 'slide',
      // 'speed' defaults to 'slow'. You can also use 'fast'
      // or a number of milliseconds for the animation to last.
      // 'speed' => 'slow',
      // Don't show any throbber... 
      'progress' => array('type' => 'none'),
    ),
  );


  $form['checkboxes_fieldset'] = array(
    '#title' => t("Generated Checkboxes"),
    // The prefix/suffix provide the div that we're replacing, named by
    // #ajax['wrapper'] above. 
    '#prefix' => '<div id="checkboxes-div">', 
    '#suffix' => '</div>', 
    '#type' => 'fieldset', 
    '#description' => t('This is where we get automatically generated checkboxes'),
  );
```

Using a popup plugin for jQuery is then possible to render as popup the `<div>` tag using that CSS ID.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Simple Dialog](http://drupal.org/project/simple_dialog) module; you can open your form in a popup modal dialog.
Other solutions might be using the [Chaos tool suite (ctools)](http://drupal.org/project/ctools) module; examples come with the module.